# Why the controller is not called?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I am making online bookstore project. I am trying to find a book by sending get request through postman using query as parameter : http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/search?query=Tolstoy. I get error 403. When I debug, I realize that when I am sending get request my controller is not called.
Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/books")
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Books>> searchBook(@RequestParam(value = "query",defaultValue = "a") String query){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bookService.searchBooks(query));
    }
}
```

Here is my Service for this controller:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService{

    private final BooksRepository booksRepository;
    @Override
    public Optional<Books> getById(Long id) {
        return booksRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Books> searchBooks(String query) {
        List<Books> booksTitle = booksRepository.searchBookByTitle(query);
        List<Books> booksGenre = booksRepository.searchBookByGenre(query);
        List<Books> booksAuthor = booksRepository.searchByAuthor(query);
        Set<Books> books = Stream.of(booksTitle,booksGenre,booksAuthor).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return books;
    }
```

Here is repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BooksRepository extends JpaRepository<Books,Long> {

    Optional<Books> findById(Long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM books b WHERE b.title LIKE (%:query%)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Books> searchBookByTitle(String query);

    @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM books b WHERE b.genre LIKE (%:query%)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Books> searchBookByGenre(String query);
    @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM books b inner join books_and_authors bas on b.id = bas.book_id " +
            "inner join authors a on bas.author_id = a.id WHERE a.name LIKE (%:query%)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Books> searchByAuthor(String query);
}
```

Appreciate any help I can get;

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SpringSecurity?
In a first look yours calls doesnt haven nothing wrong.

If you are using spring Security, verify yours permissions in your config class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can prevent your controller from receiving requests but your

`BookServiceImpl` class is missing `@Autowired` annotation before  `private final BooksRepository booksRepository;`

Try to replace

```
private final BooksRepository booksRepository;
```

With

```
@Autowired
BooksRepository booksRepository;
```